# How to view AutoCAD Format Files like .dxf in a web page

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, view, .net-6.0, autocad

I'm building a project with ASP.NET MVC, one of the features i need is to view .dwg files on my website.

So users upload .dxf file to my website and then they can view it inside a popup. The user only need to view the file, not editing it.

I hope any one can help me or point me in the right direction.

Comment: The LEADTOOLS SDK contain [HTML5/JavaScript viewer controls](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/display/html5) that can display images, documents and vector drawing files such as DXF. (Disclosure: I work for its vendor). If you wish to try these controls, you can obtain a [free evaluation here](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads).

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be embed external control like [CADViewer](https://www.cadviewer.com/)